# Where am I this Week? Challenge #2

Tags: discussion, community-event, where-am-i-challenge

The second challenge for the "Where am I?" series. Please enjoy!

## How to participate

Upload a screenshot of a game into an answer. Others will have to guess in the comments not only which game your screenshot is from, but the location within the game that the screenshot depicts.

Once someone correctly guesses your game and location, edit your answer to congratulate the winning guesser!

It is possible for there to be two winners if one person guesses the game but not the location, and a second person later jumps in with the correct location.

Keep track of incorrect guesses by editing your post to list them. This will ensure no one guesses the same thing twice.

If your screenshot features a procedurally-generated environment, please state so next to your screenshot. If this is the case, participants will only have to guess the game, not the location within.

If possible, turn off your HUD while taking the screenshot to make a harder challenge! You can also blur out the HUD, but please don't completely blacken those parts or do any other types of photo edits!

## Theme

Having trouble coming up with a good idea for a screenshot? Try something to do with **Racing**.

Comment: The game I posted a screenshot from doesn't have named locations, but it does have waypoints -- is it cool to accept the nearest waypoint as the location?

Comment: Roddy Personally I think we should generally allow the posters of the screenshots to use common sense to adjust the objective to be reasonable while staying within the "Where am I" concept. I don't think we need to be too prescriptive. That's my vision for it anyway.

Comment: I figured, but since this is a young-ish challenge I've seen the rules get adjusted one way or another so I wanted to be sure. ;)

Comment: There seems to be a serial downvoter on these challenges, may I please ask you to explain your reasoning? It would be very helpful to hear your opinion so that we can adjust these challenges to reach a point where most are satisfied.

Comment: I wish moderators had access to serial downvoter users when they, well, serial downvote and serial downvote only. I don't know why the serial downvoter dislikes the special community activity. @ExpertCoder14

Comment: @Wabbit. If they don't like the challenge, I see why they would downvote the question, but they downvoted all of its answers too. I see it as if they are bossing us around, trying to say, "Stop participating this challenge because I don't like it." How bossy!

Answer (score 5):

[image: Where am I?]

This game doesn't have named *locations* per se, but it does have waypoints. This is right near a major one, so we can use that for the "location".

---

Nobody got this one -- or even guessed. :(

The game was:

> Lost Ember

And the location was:

> Right after the beginning of Chapter II: Igniting the Fire. Move forward from the waypoint/savepoint at the beginning of the chapter, and you'll find yourself at the top of this cliff.

Comment: Seems like a cool game - but I honestly had no idea, it didn't look like anything I'd played before! :)

Comment: I have no idea why I even own it -- probably picked it up off of a Steam sale. It's ... interesting, I guess. "Atmospheric" as they say.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

"A good place to exercise"

An easy one this week, but bonus points if you can tell me how this relates to the theme.

@Wondercricket worked out that this is:

> Runescape 3

And @murgatroid99 worked out that it is at:

> The Air Altar

As well as that the reference is to:

> Racing the imp around the altar

Comment: Is that just outside the Barbarian Outpost agility course in RS3? Been a LONG time since I've played RS3, but that just what it reminds me of given the scenery and theme

Comment: @Wondercricket No, this is a different place...

Comment: That's the Air(?) Altar southeast of Barbarian Village in RS3. Is the theme relation "air rune running"? I think that's an old runecrafting training method.

Comment: I've been tricked they moved that altar, I just went looking for it in its probably pre-clans location south of Falador to see if it matched (my initial guess was the Law Altar on Entrana for similar reasons). I don't think many people run rune essence anymore, they got rid of the official Law Rune Running world on Oldschool a couple years ago

Comment: @murgatroid99 That makes much more sense. “Racing” can be the theme since your running back and forth to the Varrock bank to deposit your load

Comment: Good job team, it is the Air Altar! However that is not the racing reference. It is the start of the week so I won't give any hints yet.

Comment: Is it on the route of those terrorbird races that happen during some of the celebration events in the Lumbridge crater?

Comment: @murgatroid99 No. I'll say that, for the reference I have in mind, this is the ONLY location for it.

Comment: Is it about the part of the Imp Catcher quest where you race the imp around that altar? I did that quest long before they reworked it, so I've just seen other people do the new one.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Correct :)

Answer (score 3):

*Just here for the cheese*

[image: Planet Surface]

#### Location Hint

> Sometimes, this place is referred to as cheese

#### Game

Solved by @Wondercricket

> DuckTales: Remastered

#### Location

Solved by @JoshuaBizley

> The Moon!

Comment: I think(?) this is the DuckTales: Remastered game? Though I can't think of where exactly, or if it's even the right game ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Wondercricket DuckTales is correct! Location still up for grabs

Comment: @Robotnik That seems to suggest the answer is just "the Moon"? I haven't played the game but it obviously looks like the Moon; I just assumed the answer needed to be more specific.

Comment: @JoshuaBizley - correct! the level is literally called "The Moon", so I thought I'd keep it simple :). Though if we want to get specific this is right outside the rocket that Scrooge took to get there.

Comment: It'd also be remiss of me to not mention how epic the music of that level is, or [this excellent remix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwbMkIROOGU) of it.

Answer (score 2):

[image: a motor speedway in Microsoft Flight Simulator]

Some of the race tracks in [microsoft-flight-simulator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-flight-simulator) are not well modeled. Sometimes the sim interprets the stands as very long hotel buildings (which would actually be pretty cool). This iconic speedway however is modeled very well. Which one is it? What clues are there on-screen to allow you to identify it? (there are at least two that I know of)

### Location

Solved by @LukasRotter

> Indianapolis motor speedway

### Clues

> Start/finish line building, track layout, NAV1 tuned to the Brickyard VORTAC

Comment: Parts of this turned out slightly blurrier than I intended, in particular the BRG1 display, which is turned on intentionally. The text is "6.4NM VHP NAV1" and it corresponds to the single blue arrow on the CDI.

Comment: Looks like Indianapolis to me, given the prominent building and the last 2 turns of the track layout

Comment: @LukasRotter That is indeed the speedway roughly 7 miles east of the Brickyard (VHP) VORTAC