# Where am I this Week? Challenge #3

Tags: discussion, community-event, where-am-i-challenge

Welcome to the third challenge thread in the "Where am I?" series.

A "Where am I?" challenge involves posting a screenshot from a game and having other users guess in the comments what game it is and where in the game you are. If the game supports turning off the HUD, you are welcome to do that to increase the challenge. The content of the screenshot should contain enough identifiable information to ensure there is only one definitive answer. Other than that, you are welcome to use common sense to adjust your challenge's objective while staying within the "Where am I?" theme.

See [last week](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15788/where-am-i-this-week-challenge-2) for examples.

**Theme**

This is not mandatory but may inspire you to think of a certain environment in some game which would make for a fun challenge. This week's theme is **Dangerous Animals**.

Answer (score 6):

"Oh he was quite an interesting man..."[image]

Comment: I'm really sorry no one guessed, I just have no idea myself.

Comment: That's okay, it's a bit of a tough one for sure. It's Fafnir's Storeroom from [tag:god-of-war-2018]!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It look way too long for that dude to kill me while I was dancing.

@Topcode is correct that it is

> Fortnite

But where?

Comment: fortnite battle royale